# Recursion theory in Java

Tags: java, recursion

Oracle's documentation say's that there are three parts to creating an object
(Declaration, Instantiation and Initialization). It also 'implies' that they
"come in order", but it doesn't say this explicitly (although this generally seems to be true).

So, I am wondering if,
based on the fact that the improperly coded constructor in my example will result in recursion,
is it possible in this case (with regards to the sequence of events) that an attempt 
to instantiate the object occurs first and that (again, in this case) because of
recursion the object reference declaration never occurs....?

```
public Test(){
 Test t1 = new Test();
```

}

Comment: No, declaration always happens first

Comment: Recursion theory in any language: recursion is the first choice of a goofball and the last choice of a desperate, yet competent, programmer.

Comment: @DwB, Recursion is an elegant, compact way to describe some computations.  If elegant, compact source code had no value, then we all still would be writing in assembler.  Recursion also happens to be _practical_ for many problems.  If it weren't, then nobody would ever use it.  Also, a good compiler knows how to turn tail-recursion into an iterative function.  Yeah, there are cases where it _is_ a bad idea, but that's not true in _all_ cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaration always comes first, in fact it can happen at the start of the method, no matter where you first mention a variable (as they are created at once)

Failure to instantiate, can result in intialisation not occurring.

If a constructor does not exit normally (you will get a StackOverflowError here) the declared field or variable will not be set, an error will be thrown instead.

In the above example `t1` will not be set at any point.

> "an assignment operator is read from right to left..."

It may be helpful to think of

```
Test t1 = new Test();
```

as

```
Test t1;
t1 = new Test();
```

Comment: Ahhhh. This is the reasoning that I was looking for! Then, in terms of events, recursion (if it's present) does indeed occur following object Declaration. May sound like a no-brainer, but what prompted the question to begin with was the idea that "an assignment operator is read from right to left...".Think I was reading too deep into it. This is helpful.

Comment: @vee Added a clarification which might help.

Answer (score 2):

```
public Test(){
 Test t1 = new Test();

}
```

New instances of class Test will continue to be created until all your stack space is used up and you JVM will shutdown giving stack overflow error.

Comment: Will the instances actually be fully created?

Answer (score 0):

This is easy enough to try yourself. Try it and note the result.

```
public Test()
{
    Test t1 = new Test();
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Test t = new Test();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare an instance of the class `Test` in order for your recursion to get kicked off in the first place.  However, the instantiation for the object never returns, so the declaration never succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is an example of infinite recursion, as there is nothing there to allow us to exit the recursive loop.  As others have previously said, this will cause a stack overflow error, as the JVM will continually create and assign a memory allocation to the Test object until it runs out of space in memory.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. It is recursive and will overflow the stack. Best way to test it out is using a debugger.